# Error configuring Kubernetes to extract an image from a private registry

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I've a private repo on gitlab, this repo is synchronized with docker and trying to pull that image into my kubernetes cluster. I can see the documentations suggest to do this

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

I am already logged in, and i change path to ~/.docker/config.json but it keeps giving me

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<~/.docker/config.json> --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

bash: --type=kubernetes.io/docker config json: No such file or directory
```

Do you know how to resolve this error?

So in other words how to properly authenticate and be able to push private images into kube cluster?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need the `< >'s` in your path

Answer (score 1):

I know you've copied it from the official docs, but it may be missing quotes. Also build a path using `$HOME` var. Try this:

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson="$HOME/.docker/config.json" \
    --type="kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove "< >" while specifying path...
Rewrite the command as:

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=~/.docker/config.json \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```